# Linux sed can't read the file that's right there

Tags: linux, sed

```
grep -r -l --include=*.{html,js,css} "\bAA\b" . | xargs -0 -n 1 sed -i -e "s/\bAA\b/BB/g"
```

When I ran the above command, I got the following error:

```
sed: can't read ./login.html : No such file or directory
```

This is rather odd as I am able to `vi ./login.html`

I don't understand why am I getting this error. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `-0` with xargs unless the previous command actually uses NUL to delimit its output, which `grep` does not unless you use `-Z`. Therefore it's looking for "./login.html " and not "./login.html" (note the space).

Comment: Thanks. Dropping -0 works!
But I am curious is it a more flexible way to use the -z approach (so that I can match newline character in my regular expression)?

Comment: Correct. Without it, `xargs` will consider a newline in a filename to be an argument separator instead.